# How do I reach this location in Wurmwater?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm trying to discover all locations in Borderlands 2, but I can't seem to this location in Wurmwater.

[image: map location]

I can see this ladder, but cant figure out how to access it.

[image: ladder]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=UEq1A2Se3KI#t=74s)! It can be unlocked whilst doing the Vault Symbols challenge.

To access it, run along side until you see the walkway. Run underneath that and turn left. You'll see a small ladder which you can climb to access the previous walkway.

Passover the walkway and you come to the dish location which should unlock this area on the map.

Comment: You should at least add the video, or text directions into your answer.  A straight link to YouTube isn't very helpful.

Comment: "Vault Symbol challenge" has no duration, you can go look for Vault Symbols at any time. It is locked by another mission.

Answer (score 2):

To get there, you will need to go through the bottom of the canyon (left side from where you stand on the map) and than return along the top of the canyon. The ladder pictured is totally unaccessible from the ground, AFAIK.

You are sent to that canyon on a mission "Don't Copy That Floppy", given by [C3n50r807](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/C3n50r807) in The Washburne Refinery after/during "[Whoops](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Whoops)" main mission, if you want to save some steps.

Comment: I could access this location before I got Don't Copy That Floppy.

Comment: @squarefrog Okay, that's why I wrote "may" :) Fixing!